# Обновление Gradle в Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle

Здравствуйте! У меня такая проблема, когда захожу в File->Project Structure->Project там стоит Gradle Version 2.10, но когда набираю команду в терминале gradle --version то показывает версию 1.4 и Gradle работает именно с этой версией(1.4). В build.gradle прописано
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'. 
Как мне обновить версию Gradle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Команда `gradle --version` выводит версию градла установленного в системе, при сборке проекта же обычно используется так называемый gradle wrapper, именно его версию вы увидели на странице File->Project Structure->Project. Для работы с ним из консоли перейдите в корневую папку проекта и используйте вместо команды `gradle` команду `gradlew` (или если у вас Mac OS или Linux, то `./gradlew`).

Answer (score 9):

строка из файла *build.gradle*:

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'`

это не сам Gradle, а плагин для Android Studio, написанный Google. Он управляет взаимодействием между IDE и Gradle. Последняя текущая стабильная версия - 2.1.0. Посмотреть можно [здесь](https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.android.tools.build.gradle/view)

Версия самого Gradle для проекта указывается в файле *gradle-wrapper.properties* в строке :

```
 distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.13-all.zip
```

текущяя последняя стабильная на данный момент версия 2.13 (посмотреть можно [здесь](https://services.gradle.org/distributions/))

Указав эту строку студия закачает нужную версию, если она отсутствует и будет использовать для сборки проекта по дефолту.

Вы можете сделать то же самое через инструменты AS, проследовав по пути: *File -> Project Structure -> Project* и указав желаемые версии в соответствующих полях, отредактировав их. После нажатия кнопки OK будут изменены соответствующие конфигурационные файлы:
[image: scrn]

Для принятия изменений необходимо выполнить: *Tools -> Android -> Sync Project with Gradle files*

В настройках вам нужно указать использовать дефолтную версию враппера:

*File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Gradle -> Project-Level settings: use default gradle wrapper (recommended)*

[Официальное руководство](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html?hl=ru) по вопросу (здесь тоже можно посмотреть актуальные версии плагина и враппера).

Периодически студия может выводить уведомления о необходимости обновления плагина или враппера, их стоит принимать, так наиболее просто поддерживать актуальные версии.