# java.lang.IllegalStateException Please configure your build for VectorDrawableCompat. Есть анимация

Tags: android, gradle

Уважаемые корифеи!

Возникла следующая ситуация.

При создании MainActivity у пользователя с Android версии 4.4 возникла ошибка `java.lang.IllegalStateException` (место `android.support.v7.widget.am.a`).

Вся Трассировка стека от Гугл:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{пакет/пакет.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This app has been built with an incorrect configuration. Please configure your build for VectorDrawableCompat.
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2429)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2493)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:166)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5590)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1280)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1096)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This app has been built with an incorrect configuration. Please configure your build for VectorDrawableCompat.
    at android.support.v7.widget.am.a(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v7.widget.df.b(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v7.a.v.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v7.a.ah.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v7.a.aa.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v7.a.ab.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v7.a.u.a(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v7.a.u.a(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v7.a.s.e(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v7.a.s.onCreate(Unknown Source)
    at cf.i_ya.sales_secrets_demo.MainActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5447)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2393)
    ... 11 more
```

Попробовал реализовать совет pavlofff, долгих лет жизни ему, из другого вопроса на ru.stackoverflow:
"По всей видимости в файл конфигурации модуля приложения build.gradle нужно добавить поддержку VectorDrawable

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
}
```

"Так же версия плагина Gradle должна быть не менее 2.x.x (build.gradle всего проекта):

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
    ...
}
```

но Андроид-Стидия потребовала от меня того, чего я не понял:

> Warning:Gradle version 2.10 is required. Current version is 2.8. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in C:\android\AndroidStudioProjects\папка проекта\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-2.10-all.zip

До этого у меня версия Gradle была 1.5.х, а попытка скормить ему 2.8.0 - не увенчалась успехом.
Код MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

    SharedPreferences sPref;
    SharedPreferences.Editor ed;
    DB db;
    TextView text_0, text_1, text_2, text_3, text_4, text_5;
    Animation anim;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // полноэкранный "липкий" режим
        lipkiy();

        //получаем данные из файла "Pref"
        sPref = getSharedPreferences("Pref", MODE_PRIVATE);
        ed = sPref.edit();
        // открываем подключение к БД
        db = new DB(this);
        db.open();

        db . faq_obnovit();
        nachalo();

    }

    // приветствие и начало работы
    protected void nachalo()
    {
        text_0 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_0);
        text_1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_1);
        text_2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_2);
        text_3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_3);
        text_4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_4);
        text_5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_5);

        // создаем объект анимации из файла anim/myalpha
        anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.myalpha);

        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                    runOnUiThread(runn0);
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(4000);
                    runOnUiThread(runn1);
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(4);
                    runOnUiThread(runn2);
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(4);
                    runOnUiThread(runn3);
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(4);
                    runOnUiThread(runn4);
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(4);
                    runOnUiThread(runn5);
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(4);
                    runOnUiThread(runn6);

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
            }
        });
        t.start();
    }

    Runnable runn0 = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // запускаем анимацию
            text_0.startAnimation(anim);
            text_0 . setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    };

    Runnable runn1 = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // запускаем анимацию
            text_1.startAnimation(anim);
            text_1 . setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    };

    Runnable runn2 = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // запускаем анимацию
            text_2.startAnimation(anim);
            text_2 . setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    };

    Runnable runn3 = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // запускаем анимацию
            text_3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            text_3.startAnimation(anim);
        }
    };

    Runnable runn4 = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // запускаем анимацию
            text_4.startAnimation(anim);
            text_4 . setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    };

    Runnable runn5 = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // запускаем анимацию
            text_5.startAnimation(anim);
            text_5 . setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    };

    Runnable runn6 = new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, FAQ.class));
            MainActivity.this.finish();
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.alpha_to_1, R.anim.alpha_to_0);
        }
    };
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // закрываем подключение при выходе
        db.close();
    }
    // полноэкранный "липкий" режим
    protected void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();
        lipkiy();
    }

    // полноэкранный "липкий" режим
    protected void lipkiy ()
    {
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
    }
}
```

Возникло несколько вопросов:
1. Причиной всему использование анимации на андроиде 4.4? (на 6.0 работает)
2. Как разрешить ситуацию к лучшему при минимальных действиях?
3. Если необходимо до конца "добивать" предложение pavlofff, то что конкретно необходимо сделать? (по возможности где и на что нажимать:)? )

Возможно, важное замечание: у меня Андроид-Студия версии 1.5.2 - и выше я перейти не могу.

Comment: *Gradle version 2.10 is required* 

надо скормить версию Gradle 2.10

Comment: Но как это сделать? Просто поменять в свойствах по указанному пути руками - Gradle крутится 10 минут и не синхронизирует проект. Да и выглядит этот путь не логично. Нужно что-то обновить. Что? Непонятно также, почему компоненты 2016 года не работают для таких "старых" команд.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка значит, что требуется минимальная версия сборщика Gradle - 2.10/ Помимо минимальной версии плагина Gradle для Android Studio, так же имеет значение и версия самого Gradle.

Чтобы установить требуемую версию Gradle нужно открыть ветку gradle-файлов в левой панели Android Studio и выбрать файл *gradle-wrapper.properties*, там указать версию дистрибутива gradle, например:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip
```

здесь указана версия 2.14.1

[image: gradle]

Затем синхронизировать проект.

Так же данную настройку можно сделать с помощью графического интерфейса Android Studio, смотрите [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/529434/177345) для подробностей и больше информации по обновлению Gradle.

Comment: Гранд мерси. Все сделал по инструкции из ответа, где "с помощью графического интерфейса...". Непонятным осталось только, какая строка в MainActivity вызвала такой переполох.

Comment: @St-st думаю переполох вызвало само ваше желание использовать VectorDrawable, для этого требуется версия gradle не менее 2.10 и версия плагина gradle не менее 2.0.0

Comment: Покажите, пожалуйста, где в MainActivity использовано VectorDrawable? Единственная иконка приложения - в растре, при этом ее даже нет в MainActivity. Подозрение вызывают лишь анимации с задержкой, анимационные переходы между Окнами и полноэкранный режим ("липкий").

Comment: @St-st Дело даже не в том, что находится в MainActivity. Чтобы приложение запустилось, оно должно быть собрано сборщиком (gradle) и скомпилировано. Вы заявили поддержку VectorDrawable в конфиге сборщика, но ваша версия Gradle не может собрать эту конфигурацию. В стектрейсе все написано.