# Проблема с Gradle при работе с Flutter на Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, gradle, flutter

Обнаружил проблему при работе с **Flutter**-ом на **Android Studio**.

Начал проходить учебный курс на Udacity, установил **Dart**-плагин, **Flutter**-плагин,  и столкнулся с тем, что при импорте проекта полугодичной давности, которому нужен **Gradle** версии не ниже **4.6**, **Gradle-wrapper** выбирает версию **4.4**.

Проблема в том, что исправить это так, как описано [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/529420/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-gradle-%D0%B2-android-studio) - не выходит. Т.е. когда заходишь в `File` -> `Project Structure` -> `Project` в Android Studio из java или kotlin-проекта, то все ОК - можно выбирать версию Gradle:

[image: File -> Project Structure -> Project в Android Studio из java-проекта]

А когда идешь тем же путём из **Flutter**-проекта, то видишь следующее:

[image: File -> Project Structure -> Project в Android Studio из flutter-проекта]

Похоже, что это баг **Flutter**-плагина для **Android Studio** и выбирать версию **Gradle** из интерфейса **Android Studio** не получится.

Answer (score 2):

Проблему удалось решить только вручную, исправив в файле проекта C:\Users\...\android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties используемую в проекте версию Gradle с 4.4 на 4.6.